# Does Icelandair have a lounge in Berlin?

Tags: berlin, lounges, icelandair

Does Icelandair have a lounge in Berlin ?

The website only says "to be announced". Does anyone has recent experience with this? I also have Priority Pass, but that comes up empty for Berlin too.

Answer (score 1):

Icelandair passengers can access [Lounge Tempelhof](https://ber.berlin-airport.de/en/cafes-shops-service/sgs-poi/901-lounge-tempelhof.html) at Berlin airport. Priority Pass doesn't get you lounge access at BER, but some [credit at Mövenpick Café](https://travelwithmassi.com/priority-pass-moevenpick-cafe-flughafen-berlin-brandenburg-ber/).